# I need to remove duplicate values in my query. I have temp tables and joins. I need to group by but I am unsure of how to add the grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am including my query to help solve the issue of duplicates

```
Use B042_Arkema
SET NOCOUNT ON;
  Declare @StartDate datetime,
                @EndDate datetime

        set @StartDate =  dateadd(M,-12,getdate())
        set @EndDate = getdate()
--------get historical fleet cycle trips------------
        Select 
        Trail_ID,
        Track_ID,
        ORIGINCTY,
        ORIGINSTA,
        DESTINCTY,
        DESTINSTA,
        FINALCTY,
        FINALSTA,
        PRODUCT,
        LEP,
        abs(convert(real,DATE_TIME_ESHIP - DATE_TIME_AVAIL)) as LayDays,
        abs(convert(real,DATE_TIME_EVAIL - DATE_TIME_ESHIP))as EmptyDays
        into #trl
        from TRLSTAT
        where LEP ='P'
        and (DATE_TIME_EVAIL >= @StartDate and DATE_TIME_EVAIL <= @EndDate)
        and ORIGINCTY = FINALCTY and ORIGINSTA = FINALSTA
        Order by TRAIL_ID



--------Aggregate---------------------
        Create table #trlavg
        (
        PRODUCT varchar(50),
        ORIGINCTY varchar(50),
        ORIGINSTA char(2),
        DESTINCTY varchar(50),
        DESTINSTA char(2),
        AVGLay float,
        AVGEmpty float,
        )

        Insert into #trlavg
        Select 
        PRODUCT,
        ORIGINCTY,
        ORIGINSTA,
        DESTINCTY,
        DESTINSTA,
        AVG(LayDays) as AVGLay,
        AVG(EmptyDays) as AVGEmpty
        from #trl
        Group by 
        PRODUCT,
        ORIGINCTY,
        ORIGINSTA,
        DESTINCTY,
        DESTINSTA
        
        --select * from #trlavg


------ active loaded fleet cars in load and layover status --------------------------

        Create table #ras
        (
            Email varchar(20),
            t_Loaded bit,
            t_TripID int,
            f_UnitID varchar(10),
            f_CustomerId int,
            t_StartDate datetime,
            t_PlaceDate datetime,
            t_OriginCity varchar(35),
            t_OriginState char(2),
            t_DestinCity varchar(35),
            t_DestinState char(2),
            t_ProdDesc varchar(1000),
            t_BOLCust varchar(20),
            t_POShip varchar(20),
            t_NetWt int,
            f_Fleet varchar(25),
            f_Subfleet varchar(25),
            t_CurETA datetime,
            t_Status varchar(25),
            t_StatusCode int,
            f_LastCLMDate datetime,
            f_LastCLMLoc varchar(35),
            f_LastCLMCarrier char(5),
            f_LastCLMEvt varchar(3),
            f_EvtDesc varchar(20),
            f_LastCLMDest varchar(20),
            AVGLay float,
            AVGEmpty float,
            ActDwellDays int,
            EstEmptyRelease datetime,
            EstEmptyAvailable datetime,
            DaysOut int 

        )


        Select 
        'Arkema@qts.com' as Email,
        t_Loaded,
        t_TripID,
        f_UnitID,
        f_CustomerId,
        t_StartDate,
        t_PlaceDate,
        t_OriginCity,
        t_OriginState,
        t_DestinCity,
        t_DestinState,
        t_ProdDesc,
        t_BOLCust,
        t_POShip,
        t_NetWt,
        f_Fleet,
        f_Subfleet,
        t_CurETA,
        t_Status,
        t_StatusCode,
        f_LastCLMDate,
        f_LastCLMLoc,
        f_LastCLMCarrier,
        f_LastCLMEvt,
        f_EvtDesc1,
        f_LastCLMDest,
        case when #trlavg.AVGLay is null then 14.0 
             else cast(AVGLay as decimal(10,2))
             End as AVGLay,
        case when #trlavg.AVGEmpty is null then 14.0
             else cast(AVGEmpty as decimal(10,2)) 
             End as AVGEmpty,
        Datediff(d,t_PlaceDate,getdate()) as ActDwellDays,
        case when t_StatusCode = 1 then null
             when t_StatusCode = 2 and #trlavg.AVGLay is null then Dateadd(d,14,t_PlaceDate)
             when t_StatusCode = 2 and #trlavg.AVGLay is not null then Dateadd(d,AVGLay,t_PlaceDate) 
        End as EstEmptyRelease
        into #temp
        from Host32.dbo.RAS_TripsFleetCombo ras
        join Host32.dbo.Fleet F on ras.t_CustomerID = F.CustomerID and ras.f_UnitID = F.UnitId and F.ActiveRecord = 1
        left join #trlavg on ras.t_DestinCity = #trlavg.DESTINCTY
                         and ras.t_DestinState = #trlavg.DESTINSTA
                         and ras.t_OriginCity = #trlavg.ORIGINCTY
                         and ras.t_OriginState = #trlavg.ORIGINSTA
                         and ras.t_ProdDesc = #trlavg.PRODUCT 
        where f_CustomerID = 8 --and t_UnitID ='CEFX051288'
        and t_Loaded = 1
        and t_StatusCode in (1,2)
        and t_Origin <> t_Destination

                                          

--------Estimate empty return date  LayoverStatus  = PlaceDate + AVGLay + AVGEmpty
    INSERT into #ras
        Select
        Email,
        t_Loaded,
        t_TripID,
        f_UnitID,
        f_CustomerId,
        t_StartDate,
        t_PlaceDate,
        t_OriginCity,
        t_OriginState,
        t_DestinCity,
        t_DestinState,
        t_ProdDesc,
        t_BOLCust,
        t_POShip,
        t_NetWt,
        f_Fleet,
        f_Subfleet,
        t_CurETA,
        t_Status,
        t_StatusCode,
        f_LastCLMDate,
        f_LastCLMLoc,
        f_LastCLMCarrier,
        f_LastCLMEvt,
        f_EvtDesc1,
        f_LastCLMDest,
        AVGLay,
        AVGEmpty,
        ActDwellDays,
        case when t_StatusCode = 1 then null
             when t_StatusCode= 2 and getdate() <= EstEmptyRelease then EstEmptyRelease
             when t_StatusCode = 2 and getdate() > EstEmptyRelease then getdate()
        End as EstEmptyRelease,
        case when t_StatusCode = 1 then null
             when t_StatusCode= 2 and getdate() <= EstEmptyRelease then  getdate() + Datediff(d,getdate(),EstEmptyRelease) + AVGEmpty
             when t_StatusCode = 2 and getdate() > EstEmptyRelease then Dateadd(d,AVGEmpty,getdate())
        End as EstEmptyAvailable,
        case  when  t_StatusCode = 1 then null
              when t_StatusCode= 2 and getdate() <= EstEmptyRelease then DateDiff(d,getdate(), getdate() + Datediff(d,getdate(),EstEmptyRelease) + AVGEmpty)
               when t_StatusCode = 2 and getdate() > EstEmptyRelease then Datediff(d,getdate(),  Dateadd(d,AVGEmpty,getdate()))
        End as DaysOut
        from #temp
        Order by f_UnitID

-----Insert Empty  with Days Out logic and include  Shop cars

        INSERT into #ras
        Select 
        'Arkema@qts.com' as Email,
        t_Loaded,
        t_TripID,
        f_UnitID,
        f_CustomerId,
        t_StartDate,
        t_PlaceDate,
        t_OriginCity,
        t_OriginState,
        t_DestinCity,
        t_DestinState,
        t_ProdDesc,
        t_BOLCust,
        t_POShip,
        t_NetWt,
        f_Fleet,
        f_Subfleet,
        t_CurETA,
        t_Status,
        t_StatusCode,
        f_LastCLMDate,
        f_LastCLMLoc,
        f_LastCLMCarrier,
        f_LastCLMEvt,
        f_EvtDesc1,
        f_LastCLMDest,
        null as AVGLay,
        null as AVGEmpty,
        null as ActDwellDays,
        null as EstEmptyRelease,
        t_CurETA as EstEmptyAvailable,
        case when t_StatusCode in ( 3,5) then Datediff(d,getdate(),t_CurETA)
             when t_StatusCode = 4 then null
        End as DaysOut
    
        
        from Host32.dbo.RAS_TripsFleetCombo ras
        join Host32.dbo.Fleet F on ras.t_CustomerID = F.CustomerID and ras.t_UnitID = F.UnitId and F.ActiveRecord = 1
        where f_CustomerID = 8
        and t_StatusCode in (3,4,5)
        and t_Origin <> t_Destination

--Not in Active Tracking Cars-----------
        INSERT into #ras
        Select 
        'Arkema@qts.com' as Email,
        case when f_LastCLMLoaded ='L' then 1 
             when f_LastCLMLoaded = 'E' then 0
             else null End as t_Loaded,
        null as t_TripID,
        f_UnitID,
        f_CustomerId,
        null as t_StartDate,
        null as t_PlaceDate,
        null as t_OriginCity,
        null as t_OriginState,
        null as t_DestinCity,
        null as t_DestinState,
        null as t_ProdDesc,
        null as t_BOLCust,
        null as t_POShip,
        t_NetWt,
        f_Fleet,
        f_Subfleet,
        t_CurETA,
        t_Status,
        t_StatusCode,
        f_LastCLMDate,
        f_LastCLMLoc,
        f_LastCLMCarrier,
        f_LastCLMEvt,
        f_EvtDesc1,
        f_LastCLMDest,
        null as AVGLay,
        null as AVGEmpty,
        null as ActDwellDays,
        null as EstEmptyRelease,
        null as EstEmptyAvailable,
        null as DaysOut
    
        
        from Host32.dbo.RAS_TripsFleetCombo ras
        join Host32.dbo.Fleet F on ras.f_CustomerID = F.CustomerID and ras.f_UnitID = F.UnitId and F.ActiveRecord = 1
        where f_CustomerID = 8
    --nd t_StatusCode = 6




        Select * from #ras
        Order by f_UnitID

        drop table #trl
        drop table #trlavg
        drop table #temp
        drop table #ras
```

I tried group by but I am unsure of how to add the group by to stop the duplication

Comment: This is a lot of code with no context at all. We don't know what those tables are, the column names are so abstract nobody knows what they are and we have no idea what you are trying to accomplish. There does seem to be multiple layers of complexity here that are likely not needed.

Comment: Please check the guide How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).